# curl exec 504 timeout nginx

Tags: curl, php-curl

I am trying to parse this website: http://www.mz.gov.kz/ru/news, but I am getting an 504 error. After I changing `connection_timeout` to 60 sec I get `28 error: connect timed out`. On another server it works good. Maybe my IP was blocked, I don't know. My function is

```
function get_web_page($url)
    {
      $uagent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";  
      $ch = curl_init( $url );   
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);  
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);        
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);   
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"d://coo.txt");    
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err = curl_errno( $ch );
      $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
      $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
      curl_close( $ch );
      $header['errno']   = $err;
      $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
      $header['content'] = $content;
    //echo $errmsg.'s<br>';
      /*foreach($header as $key=>$value){
          echo $key.' -- > '.$value.'<br>';
      }*/
      return $header;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid.

A `504` error means that some problem occurred **on the server side** and specifically that the request you made requires (to be executed) more time than the maximum allowed by the server configuration, in this case something between 60 and 120 seconds.

If the response error code is "genuine" then the server may be overloaded or your're actually making a specific request that causes a timeout.

Another option may be that your IP is banned and the server just let the connetion timeout as a "defense" measure althought this would be quite uncommon (from my experience).
Normally when an IP is banned the connection is just refused. Easier to implement and less resource consuming.